Is there any reason _not_ to add a flyback diode?
When using a MOSFET to power an inductive load like a motor, relay etc., it's well-established that you should add a reverse-biased diode across the load to protect from any kickback.
I'm making a general-purpose reusable MOSFET breakout that could be used by a microprocessor to control various outputs - e.g. a 12V Motor, or relay, but also could just be an LED.
Besides a (barely noticeable) increase in BoM parts, is there any reason why I shouldn't include a diode D1 across the output MOT terminals in all cases? (I can't think of any, but just wanted to make sure!) TIA.


Regarding the circuit in general, is your microcontroller’s output high enough voltage and current to properly drive the FET? Might need a two stage approach or even better a dedicated driver IC if you want to use power FETs especially if you want to drive them in a high frequency PWM pattern.

A more rugged solution would be to use a MOSFET driver with various protection built-in (reverse voltage, overcurrent, overtemperature etc). Then you probably get the appropriate logic level voltage on the gate too, which might not be the case if you have some generic N channel and toggle it with 3.3V.


More BOM items and more cost.

If it fails short Q1 will fail, perhaps dramatically.

Potentially leakage current could be consideration under some oddball circumstance (Schottky diode, very high temperature, light load). For example, a B540C SMC Schottky can leak 0.5mA at 25° and 20mA at 100°C and still be in spec.

In the case of a motor, the motor (as a voltage source) may be able to back-drive your power supply through the diode, with possibly unwanted consequences. When I push the bed around on a certain 3D printer (with power off), the display lights up!

As Kevin says, you may not want to slow the release time of a relay or solenoid. The user will need something most likely if your MOSFET is not avalanche rated, but a diode might have to be removed to allow a more optimum method.


.. by and large, I don't think it's a bad idea to put a diode in there, most of the above points are mitigated if there is a good possibility of field failures due to the user not reading the manual and hooking a motor or solenoid onto the output.

In the case of driving a relay a diode will slow down the release time that may not be desirable.

A reversed (DC brushed) motor will be shorted (braked). (Would a BLDC back-drive, regardless of direction?) Another knock-on opportunity: the leakage helps keep weak/nonlinear loads "off", LED strings for example (which can otherwise glow dimly or blink from switch leakage). Worth mentioning: a VIN bypass capacitor or TVS should be nearby.

Thanks! I'm happy to disregard 1.) and 2.) since I'm producing these units in the tens (or maybe hundreds), not tens of thousands, and I don't see any reason why it should fail (there are many more likely components that will die first, and I can't protect against all of them!)
3.) and 4.) are interesting. I'm not sure I totally understand the situations in which they may happen.... but it sounds on balance there would be more risk (in my particular application) to not including the diode, so I think I'll incorporate it by default. Cheers!

How does D1 contribute to back-driving the power supply? When the motor drives V+ positive and V- negative, the body diode of the MOSFET is all that's needed to complete the circuit. D1 just shorts out the opposite polarity, which is anyway blocked by the body diode.

@TooTea Yes, I think you're right on that point.

Yes, many reasons.
Whatever inductive load you are driving, a diode is usually the first thing people put there because it's the most simple option, and very effective for protecting the FET from damage, but it may be the worst ever option for your load, such as a relay, solenoid or motor.
As the diode has low voltage drop, any flyback current the inductive load will push through the diode will dissipate very little energy, and thus for example a relay will open slowly, and slowly opening contacts have higher resistance before they open, and thus may heat up more when opening, and any arcs that form between contacts will burn longer as the contacts open more slowly under slowly decaying magnetic field.
So whatever you put there, you should know if it is best for the transistor or for the load and what to put there as a snubber may depend on what is best or even OK for the inductive load.
Having just a diode there means it might not be possible to use other methods more suitable for the load any more.

Because you are \$\text{making a general-purpose reusable MOSFET breakout}\$, adding a diode to protect the MOSFET (part of your design) is not sufficient. For instance, what if the customer decided to use an external supply that is significantly bigger than what you had considered?
You say the intended use is at 12 volt so, wouldn't it be preferable to add a Zener diode in parallel with each MOSFET to do the protecting should someone decide to use (say) 24 volts or 48 volts and not use the Vin connection: -

The diode is made redundant by the external wiring and, your MOSFET might be subject to significant overvoltage.
Yes, I'm talking about potential abuse by a customer/end-user and making sure you have more bases covered. I'd also consider adding a fuse in series with each MOSFRET drain for similar reasons.

Everyone else has suggested some good general suggestions but
I'll post something specific. In a pulse induction metal detector, back EMF is actually the intent of the design. A current is pulsed through a coil and the resultant back EMF is measured. A change in the EMF measured can determine if metal is present within the magnetic field of the coil. A flyback diode would disrupt this process.
